# Voice Menu Example - JetBrains MPS - How to build, compile and run the example project

Tags: jetbrains-ide, mps

I'm trying to learn the DSL workbench JetBrains MPS. One of their examples is the Phone Voice Menu as found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVIywLXDuRo) and the source code [here](https://github.com/vaclav/voicemenu).

Upon opening the project in MPS. I have this warning/error highlight regarding *[dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uotJM.png)*.

How do I execute this project to reproduce the Voice Menu demonstration as shown in the example video from JetBrains? The video talks a lot about how text-to-speech library is used to simulate the voice menu commands etc, but it is on a very high level and skips the exact steps to reproduce the result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to worry about this warning, it will not affect generation.

I suggest you to use *MPS 2018.1.5* and latest *master* of VoiceMenu project.
You should be able to rebuild project in this configuration.

Use one of examples from **jetbrains.mps.samples.VoiceMenu.sandbox** and open it in editor.

[image]

Next use intention menu to switch generation target to Java:

[image]

[image]

If you don't see this option, that mean it has already been chosen.

Rebuild solution after switching to Java Simulator. This will generate required java classes to run it.

Now you should be able to run simulator from context menu:

[image]

Note, that voice generation (quality and voice itself) will be different for different OS.

Comment: I was looking for that 'Light bulb' all the time. This explanation made everything clear.